# Verify HMAC signature in WCF web service in .NET Framework

Tags: asp.net, wcf, docusignapi, hmac, docusignconnect

I'm trying to implement HMAC security in a WCF web service, but am having a hard time verifying the HMAC signature. I am using .NET Framework 4.8.

I'm following DocuSign API documentation here:
https://developers.docusign.com/platform/webhooks/connect/validate/

Their documentation provides code samples, specifically in "Step 2: Verify the HMAC signature":

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

public static class HMACValidation
{
    public static string ComputeHash(string secret, string payload)
    {
        byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret);
        HMAC hmac = new HMACSHA256(bytes);
        bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);

        return Convert.ToBase64String(hmac.ComputeHash(bytes));
    }

    public static bool HashIsValid(string secret, string payload, string verify)
    {
       ReadOnlySpan<byte> hashBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(ComputeHash(secret, payload));
       ReadOnlySpan<byte> verifyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(verify);

       return CryptographicOperations.FixedTimeEquals(hashBytes, verifyBytes);
    }
}
```

Per Microsoft, `CryptographicOperations.FixedTimeEquals` is only for: .NET Core 2.1, 2.2, 3.0, 3.1, .NET 5, .NET 6, .NET 7

So I'm unable to use this code sample in .NET Framework 4.8.

**Question 1**: in .NET Framework 4.8, is there another way to verify the HMAC signature?

I was unable to find an alternative, so I tried a similar approach to the Microsoft article below.

[A Guide to Designing and Building RESTful Web Services with WCF 3.5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/articles/dd203052(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#implementing-authentication-and-authorization)

So, I implemented the following in my WCF service, in hopes to work-around the `CryptographicOperations.FixedTimeEquals`:

```
public string DocuSign(DocuSignWebhookRequest jsonRequest)
{
    var payload = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(jsonRequest);
    var secretKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HMAC_Key"];
    var verifyKey = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["x-docusign-signature-1"];

    var computedHashString = ComputeHash(secretKey, payload);
    var valid = computedHashString.Equals(verifyKey); // false
}

private string ComputeHash(string secret, string payload)
{
    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret);
    HMAC Mac = new HMACSHA256(bytes);
    bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(payload);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(Mac.ComputeHash(bytes));
}
```

**Question 2**: any ideas why my code is not able to verify the HMAC signature? It's always returning false when comparing to the verify key sent by DocuSign.

Comment: Both codes differ *only* in comparing the data, the first code compares the byte arrays with `FixedTimeEquals()`, the second compares the Base64 encoded data with `String.Equals()`. If the first code validates successfully, the second one validates successfully too (if you pass identical data), s. [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TDnxpP) If this is not the case for you, post non-productive data with which the issue can be reproduced. Otherwise, the problem is more likely to be your data, which may be inconsistent.

Comment: If you want to fix the vulnerability with the non-constant time comparison under .NET Framework, implement `FixedTimeEquals()` yourself. On the web you can find implementations (e.g. [here](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.IdentityModel/System/IdentityModel/CryptoHelper.cs#L1141)) .

Comment: @Topaco thank you. I copied the .NET Core implementation as per the link you recommended and am using that. Seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an official document which shows how to sign a file by using the HMACSHA256 object and then how to verify the file: [HMACSHA256 Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.hmacsha256?view=netframework-4.8).

About the second question, the code you post have substituted in the actual value. I'm not sure if this will cause a problem.

Comment: That's not really an answer to the question, more of a comment. And if the link eventually stops working, this answer is actually worthless.